# how to set conditions for compact() in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i have to controller: uploads and papers

a paper hasMany uploads. 
in add controller i have this code for select paper:

```
$this->set(compact('paper'));
```

now how i can set conditions to show papers in dropdown that just show users submited papers?

Comment: you dont select anything with this. you are only passing the variable $paper to the view. nothing else. you are missing the actual retrieval statement here.

Comment: for starters posting the whole action - not just the irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery which returns all the papers_id in the upload table. Then call the papers whose id match.

Cakephp docs:[Sub-queries](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries)

Answer (score 0):

you also have find('list') in your code, add your conditions for the find.
Example:

```
$papers = $this->Upload->Paper->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Paper.active' => true)));
```